# Shortening JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript

I must admit, I don't know much about JavaScript that is why my question might sound little bit silly.

But what I'm trying to do is grab values from selected by name radio groups.

It looks like this

```
function calc() {
    var op1 = document.getElementsByName('form[radio1]');
    var op2 = document.getElementsByName('form[radio2]');
    var op3 = document.getElementsByName('form[radio3]');

    var result = document.getElementById('result');

    result.value = 0;

    result.value = parseInt(result.value);

    for (i = 0; i < op1.length; i++) {
        if (op1[i].checked) result.value = parseInt(result.value) + parseInt(op1[i].value);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < op2.length; i++) {
        if (op2.options[i].selected) result.value = parseInt(result.value) + parseInt(op2[i].value);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < op3.length; i++) {
        if (op3.options[i].selected) result.value = parseInt(result.value) + parseInt(op3[i].value);
    }

    return false;
}
```

And this is my form. Im using rs form for joomla.

```
<form action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="userForm" method="post">

    <input name="form[radio1]" value="25" id="radio20" type="radio">
        <label for="radio20">Description1</label>

    <input name="form[radio1]" value="35" id="radio21" type="radio">
        <label for="radio21">Description2</label>



    <input name="form[radio2]" value="20" id="radio20" type="radio">
    <label for="radio20">Description1</label>

    <input name="form[radio2]" value="30" id="radio21" type="radio">
    <label for="radio21">Description2</label>


    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="result" name="form[result]">

    <input type="submit" class="rsform-submit-button" onclick="calc()" id="submit" name="form[submit]" value="submit">
```

And everything would be OK, as the function is working. the only trouble is that I have about 80 radiograms.

Is there a way to shorten it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use arrays of objects (like all the radio buttons, for instance) and iterate over them. Start like this:

```
var opts = [],
    numOpts = 80;

for (var i=0; i<numOpts, i++)
{
    opts.push(document.getElementsByName('form[radio' + i + ']'));
}
```

---

**Edit:** let's have a go at the full function. The only thing I'm not 100% sure about is whether you mean to use `opX[i].checked` or `opX.options[i].selected` (since your code does different things for `op1` and `op2/3`). Shouldn't be too hard to extrapolate if I've guessed wrong, though.

```
function calc()
{
    var opts = [],
        numOpts = 80,
        value = 0,
        result = document.getElementById('result'),
        i, j, opt;

    for (i=0; i<numOpts; i++)
    {
        opts.push(document.getElementsByName('form[radio' + i + ']'));
    }

    numOpts = opts.length;

    for (i=0; i<numOpts; i++)
    {
        opt = opts[i];
        for (j=0; j<opt.length; j++)
        {
            // or did you mean:
            // if (opt.options[j].selected) ?
            if (opt[j].checked)
            {
                value = value + parseInt(opt[j].value, 10);
            }
        }
    }

    result.value = value;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Irs great i believe, the thing is that I simply dont know JavaScript. So I might simply ask for function that will work please?

Comment: @Dom see my edit. I think I've re-created what your function was trying to do. That said, if you "simply don't know JavaScript" then perhaps you should work on _actively_ learning it rather than _asking for the answer_.

Comment: @ Matt I completely agree with you. And this is my next step. Im kind of beginner with jQuery  and JavaScript and please believe me, but this one - I just needed solution. Unfortunately this doesn't work form me. I really need help on that. Desperate. Is there anything else I need to post to help out with finding solution?

Comment: @Dom: I'm not a psychic and I don't have a crystal ball. You need to describe, **precisely**, what isn't working: **what** should be happening, and **what** is happening instead? It might also be helpful if you could show some of the relevant HTML. An online tool like http://jsfiddle.net is extremely useful.

Comment: @Matt Thank you for your hely. Really. Ive just added my html. Basically want summarise all the values.

Comment: @Matt, Thank you so much. I have find the error:Problem at line 9 character 24: Expected ';' and instead saw ','.
for (i=0; i<numOpts, i++), Thank you for your help. Works Perfect!

Comment: @Dom: **augh, sorry!** That was absolutely a typo on my part. Fixing the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a great library that's like using JavaScript on steroids. It is well worth learning and there are plenty of examples out in the wild.

You can write complex "[selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)" quite like this:

```
$('input[name=form[radio1]]').attr('checked').each(function() {
      result.value = $(this).attr('value')
})
```

(I'm not sure if it will accept a name like "form[radio1]" as valid, but give it a try.

Comment: You would need to escape the `[]` like `\\\[`. And would probably want to use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with/) like `'input[name^=form\\\[radio]'`.

Comment: I don't know whether to +1 or -1 this answer, for recommending jQuery.

Comment: @Matt - Yeah, I don't really like it when unsolicited js library solutions are given.